# How to set FlushMode to COMMIT in SPRING DATA for a single method

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data

I would like to make a single method to run without the FlushMode.ALWAYS.

So I need to `setFlushMode(FlushMode.COMMIT)` but I don't know how to do that and I'm starting to think that it's not possible using spring data.

I tried to autowire SessionFactory and do this

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().setFlushMode(FlushMode.COMMIT);
```

But I got this error

```
No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency...
```

What I understand is that I can't autowire session factory, so I can't use that way of setting flush mode.

Then my question is

Is there a way to set flush mode for a single method using spring data? How?

Comment: why do you want to do this?

Comment: There is a big bad code in a legacy app that sets a lot of things to query a single thing. That query flush is throwing an exception that shouldn't be thrown

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I ended annotating my find method in my JPARepository interface like this:

```
@QueryHints(value = { @QueryHint(name = org.hibernate.annotations.QueryHints.FLUSH_MODE, value = "COMMIT") })
    List<ConcatenaCep> findByCep(Integer cep);
```

Comment: Defo a lifesaver. Had a query that ran 18k times within the same transaction with an additional 18k saves that needed 231 seconds. Finally found out how to change flush mode and reduced the time to 17 seconds.

Comment: this looks good and is not deprecated,  but spring just decides to save everything either way in my case, even with "MANUAL" value.